# Visual Studio 2017 can't load solutions The "Package" package did not load correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I recently used the repair function in my Visual Studio Installer that I thought could fix the error message: **Microsoft data transformation services designer package did not load correctly**. However it turns out there is a new error message when I wanted to load my previous project: **The "Package" package did not load correctly**.

[image]

If I continue the loading, I will receive some other warning message in the solution Explorer saying my project is "incompatible" and "the application is not installed":

[image]

I initially also tried to follow some online solution and tried to repair Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools in control panel. It doesn't allow me to repair and says Setup Failed almost immediately after I click on the repair button.

Initially I was trying to add an WCF extenion in Visual Studio but seemed failed and threw the first error message to me. Then when I try to repair, the first error message is gone and I was given the second error message. Now I stuck in there.

I have also checked if SSDT is included in the installer and New project types:

[image]   [image]

It seems the SSDT is selected in the Visual Studio Installer and all my current project types are listed in the screenshot as well (previously I was able to see Integration services as well but now after the repair I can't).

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 on a test server that a few people have access to (I've also tried to restart the Visual Studio and the server but it didn't help).

Hope I can get some suggestions here, really appreciated.

Comment: This seems to suggest you don't have SSDT installed. Have you installed the extension for VS3027? When trying to create a new project, can you see the SSDT project types? If the repair/install is failing, what do the logs say?

Comment: @Larnu Hi, I just checked some of what you said and post the screenshot in my question. I'm not sure if I looked in the right place but in the Visual Studio Installer, I have SSDT selected but some of the project types in the New project went missing. In terms of VS3027, I'm not sure where I should find it. There are several error messages: 1) Still unable to load MEF component DLL; 2) LegacySitePackage failed for package [Package]Source.

Comment: VS 3027 was a typo, meant 2017  hav youbch fked the install logs though?

Comment: Can you reload the project by right-clicking in the Solution Explorer?